# Using the Python math.prod() in a specified Pandas date range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I'm relatively new to Python but I have a complicated issue which I think requires a few different functions, but I don't know where to start.

It's kind of straightforward to do in Excel, by using the PRODUCT function, based on a starting point up to the most recent renewal date (in this example it would be 01/10/2020) and simply multiplying this Product function totals of each of the starting point elements, to give the current renewal date total, broken down by element values.

I want to write this in Python but besides the very basic info on Python 3.8 math.prod(), there doesn't seem to be anything more that I can find online to resolve/assist me with this.

I have the following 3 Pandas dataframes (I copied the data from Excel and pasted in the links below for ease of the explanation, but I've imported these as dataframes in my test code).

The data comes in this form which need to be collated together and a revaluation, broken down by the different elements of a member's entitlement, needs to go from the starting date ("StartDate") to the current “renewal” date (01/10/2020) - if possible, there also needs to be a pro-rata done in complete months between the StartDate to the 1st renewal date (equivalent to the Excel YEARFRAC function).

The 3 dataframes are:

1. Identifiers of members with certain basic information. The most important piece of data is the ‘StartDate’ column, as it's the point to revalue member benefits from. It needs to have a function that calculates, I'm guessing here, the TimeDelta (in months) from the StartDate to the member's 1st renewal date, which needs to be a pro-rata of the difference e.g. 1st member started on 01/02/2016 so the 1st renewal needs to have a pro-rata of 8 months. I'd also like to set a boolean where if True, the pro-rata occurs otherwise it doesn't

[List of MemberIDs and StartDates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vip9U.png)

2. Increase factors. The elements will either increase or stay level (never decrease in value)

[Increase rates by year (index used is the Renewal Date)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRC5w.png)

3. Member assets - linked to (1) by the member identifier (MemberID). These different elements should escalate by the increase factors in (2) and these figures are the elements as at the StartDate.

[StartDate elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQHQO.png)

Essentially, the function(s) need to calculate when the first renewal date is after the StartDate, apply a pro-rata increase if the boolean is True, then work out the range of renewal dates and increase factors between the StartDate and the latest renewal date and finally apply the Product for this date range on the StartDate elements.

With this being my first ever post, my apologies if it's not quite in the format you might expect or with any Python code as I'm very new to Python and to StackOverflow (they wouldn't even allow me to post the tables directly, only as links to images). The data I've provided, due to data protection, are dummy dates but relatively based on the actual data.

Any questions you have, I'm happy to provide more information. Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT:
Please see this temporary solution that I'm using, but it's without the pro-rata of the 1st increase between StartDate to the 1st increase date:
[Solution (without pro-rata)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKCl9.png)

- The MemberID in the example, the Python function should find the 1st increase after StartDate as 01/10/2016 (DD/MM/YYYY)
- The function should then check the Renewal Date increases by each element between 01/10/2016 and the latest Renewal Date at 01/10/2020. The Excel PRODUCT formula gives the element increases as: 1.38823, 1.20396 and 1.20462 for elements 1 to 3 respectively
- Finally, the elements from the StartDate are multiplied by the PRODUCT totals of each tranche, to give the current value

Comment: Honestly, I do not understand anything of what you said. But if you try to emulate Excel behavior with python pandas lib, I think that should be possible. I do not think you need the Math prod method. Pandas is more powerful. You can also filter group, use aggregate funktions and so on. As I do not understand you problem, I can not set you in the right direction. But if you learn a bit more of python and pandas you might help yourselve. See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmEHCJofslg&feature=emb_rel_pause

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've seen that video before, Keith Galli is very good but this vide simply doesn't answer my question. In fact, most introductory videos on Pandas and the Python math module have very basic information/instructions and none that I've seen have helped  with my problem. The solution i believe is a combination of writing a function that can perform the three steps, either in one function or 2-3 functions combined. I've edited my question with what I'm after in another screenshot from Excel, which keeps crashing when trying to do this and I want to build a Python solution

Comment: The Edit make it clear. Now I think I understand the problem. The picture of the Excel and the three list items tell me more then the complete rest of the text. You found a better, miore understable way to ask and (BANG!) you got an answer. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've whipped something up here that should give you a primer. The first code block just recreates your data. The second block iterates over each member, gets the appropriate renewal dates, and then just multiplies the fetched rows across the DataFrames.

It's not as efficient as it could be due to using the explicit for-loop over member ids instead of broadcasting, but it should get you started.

```py
import pandas as pd

df_startDate = pd.DataFrame({
    'StartDate': pd.to_datetime(['01/02/2016', '10/04/2017', '29/09/2018', '05/11/2018']),
}, index=['9000001', '9000023', '9004561', '9007910'])

df_renewals = pd.DataFrame({
    'Element 1': [1.05, 1.04, 1.06, 1.10, 1.08, 1.06],
    'Element 2': [1.03, 1.02, 1.07, 1.05, 1.03, 1.02],
    'Element 3': [1.04, 1.04, 1.05, 1.03, 1.02, 1.05],
}, index=pd.to_datetime(['01/10/'+str(i) for i in range(2015, 2021)]))

df_assets = pd.DataFrame({
    'Element 1': [1000, 1500, 2000, 1750],
    'Element 2': [1500, 2000, 2500, 2000],
    'Element 3': [2000, 2500, 3000, 2250],
}, index=['9000001', '9000023', '9004561', '9007910'])

print(df_startDate)
print(df_renewals)
print(df_assets)
```

My approach that you can study:

```py
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Element 1', 'Element 2', 'Element 3'])

for member_id in df_startDate.index:
    print('******')
    print(member_id)
    
    # Get rows between the StartDate and the current date
    df_factors = df_renewals.loc[df_startDate['StartDate'].loc[member_id]: pd.Timestamp.now()]
    print(df_factors, end='\n\n')
    
    # Multiply rows together to get total factor
    prod_factors = df_factors.product(axis='index')
    print(prod_factors.to_frame().T, end='\n\n')
    
    # Multiply factor with base value
    results.loc[member_id] = df_assets.loc[member_id].mul(prod_factors)
    print(results.loc[member_id].to_frame().T, end='\n\n')

print(results)
```

Without comments/printing:

```py
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Element 1', 'Element 2', 'Element 3'])
for member_id in df_startDate.index:
    df_factors = df_renewals.loc[df_startDate['StartDate'].loc[member_id]: pd.Timestamp.now()]
    results.loc[member_id] = df_assets.loc[member_id].mul( df_factors.product(axis='index') )
```

Result:

```
           Element 1    Element 2   Element 3
9000001  1388.230272  1805.934123  2409.23592
9000023  1888.920000  2206.260000  2757.82500
9004561  2289.600000  2626.500000  3213.00000
9007910  2003.400000  2101.200000  2409.75000
```